# Proper Groovy List

Tags: groovy

I have a two List object like aList and bList.

```
def aList = [Spring, Bootstrap,jquery]
def bList = [700, 800,900]
```

I want some final result in a object from aList and bList like :

```
[['Spring',700],['Bootstrap',800],['jquery',900]]
```

Please help to to get the result
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a Groovy one-liner: `[aList, bList].transpose()`

Comment: Thank you, Gregor Petrin
Actully i was trying some groovy code base stuff but it become complex, yours is a great one !..
Sorry, due to having less reputation could not reward you.

Comment: Glad to be of help, you can probably accept the answer regardless of your reputation as you're the one who posted the question :)